# SQL Splitting SUM Rows into Columns based on Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to SUM values into columns based on dates.

This is my current SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    FORMAT(dbo.DR_INVLINES.TRANSDATE, 'MMM') AS Month, 
    dbo.DR_ACCS.NAME, 
    SUM(dbo.DR_INVLINES.QUANTITY * dbo.STOCK_ITEMS.X_LITERAGE) AS SUMQTY, 
    FORMAT(dbo.DR_INVLINES.TRANSDATE, 'yy') AS Year
FROM
    dbo.DR_INVLINES 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.DR_TRANS ON dbo.DR_INVLINES.HDR_SEQNO = dbo.DR_TRANS.SEQNO 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.STOCK_ITEMS ON dbo.DR_INVLINES.STOCKCODE = dbo.STOCK_ITEMS.STOCKCODE  
INNER JOIN
    dbo.DR_ACCS ON dbo.DR_INVLINES.ACCNO = dbo.DR_ACCS.ACCNO
GROUP BY 
    FORMAT(dbo.DR_INVLINES.TRANSDATE, 'yy'), 
    FORMAT(dbo.DR_INVLINES.TRANSDATE, 'MMM'), 
    dbo.STOCK_ITEMS.STOCKGROUP, dbo.DR_ACCS.NAME
HAVING        
    (dbo.STOCK_ITEMS.STOCKGROUP = 3)
```

This query returns this result set:

```
Mth Name       SUMQTY   Year
-----------------------------
Apr Company 1    1000   16
Apr Company 2   30790.4 16
Apr Company 3    1840   16
Apr Company 1    6502.9 17
Apr Company 2    2000   17
Apr Company 3    1000   17
```

What I am trying to achieve is

```
Mth Name        2016    2017
-------------------------------
Apr Company 1     800     200
Apr Company 2   15000   13000
Apr Company 3     600     569
Apr Company 1    5000    1500
Apr Company 2    2000    1986
Apr Company 3    1000    2543
```

Can someone please help with this..... I have been racking my brain for ages on this one  ;-)

Comment: check out `PIVOT`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `group by`?

```
SELECT FORMAT(il.TRANSDATE, 'MMM') AS Month, a.NAME, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN year(il.TRANSDATE) = 2016 THEN anil.QUANTITY * si.X_LITERAGE END) AS SUMQTY_2017, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN year(il.TRANSDATE) = 2017 THEN anil.QUANTITY * si.X_LITERAGE END) AS SUMQTY_2016 
FROM dbo.DR_INVLINES il INNER JOIN
     dbo.DR_TRANS t
     ON il.HDR_SEQNO = t.SEQNO INNER JOIN
     dbo.STOCK_ITEMS si
     ON il.STOCKCODE = si.STOCKCODE INNER JOIN
     dbo.DR_ACCS a
     ON il.ACCNO = a.ACCNO
WHERE si.STOCKGROUP = 3
GROUP BY FORMAT(il.TRANSDATE, 'MMM'), a.NAME;
```

Note the changes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- The `having` clause is on an unaggregated column, so it should be a `where` clause.
- You had an extra column in the `group by`.
- I would recommend using `datepart()` or `datename()` over `format()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you wanted to display `YEAR` as column,

```
SELECT  FORMAT(dbo.DR_INVLINES.TRANSDATE, 'MMM') AS Month, 
        dbo.DR_ACCS.NAME, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(dbo.DR_INVLINES.TRANSDATE) = 2016 
                THEN dbo.DR_INVLINES.QUANTITY * dbo.STOCK_ITEMS.X_LITERAGE
                ELSE 0
                END ) AS [2016], 
        SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(dbo.DR_INVLINES.TRANSDATE) = 2017 
                THEN dbo.DR_INVLINES.QUANTITY * dbo.STOCK_ITEMS.X_LITERAGE
                ELSE 0
                END ) AS [2017]
FROM    dbo.DR_INVLINES 
        INNER JOIN dbo.DR_TRANS 
            ON dbo.DR_INVLINES.HDR_SEQNO = dbo.DR_TRANS.SEQNO 
        INNER JOIN dbo.STOCK_ITEMS 
            ON dbo.DR_INVLINES.STOCKCODE = dbo.STOCK_ITEMS.STOCKCODE 
        INNER JOIN dbo.DR_ACCS 
            ON dbo.DR_INVLINES.ACCNO = dbo.DR_ACCS.ACCNO
WHERE   dbo.STOCK_ITEMS.STOCKGROUP = 3
GROUP   BY FORMAT(dbo.DR_INVLINES.TRANSDATE, 'yy'), 
        FORMAT(dbo.DR_INVLINES.TRANSDATE, 'MMM'), 
        dbo.STOCK_ITEMS.STOCKGROUP, 
        dbo.DR_ACCS.NAME
```